# Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider

Tags: react-native

My project has developed in Reactnative Expo. When I start the app, I have got this error **Tried to register two views with the same name RNCSafeAreaProvider**. I have no idea about his bug. I have already removed and reinstalled node_modules and package.json, package-lock.json.

Kindly share your ideas. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: This might help https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110

Comment: Tried this method already. Still having issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried the solution offered [in this Github issue](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context/issues/110) but no luck.

Upgrading `expo` to `~40.0.0` and `react-native-safe-area-context` to `3.1.9` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I fixed the issue on SDK 42.0.0:

Open your app route folder -> `node_modules` -> `invariant` -> `browser.js`

In the file `browser.js`, remove the `[if condition code]` (line number 28 to 46 )

My `package.json` file given below:

```
"expo": "~42.0.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",

"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
```

Comment: Really? Why do we have to go this way? Any other ways you could possibly give?

Comment: terrible, editing node_modules is never the solution